# How to import Swift module with plus (+) sign in Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to import a module called "[NSObject+Rx](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/NSObject-Rx)" but Xcode complains with an obscure error (consecutive statements separated with ; etc).

```
import NSObject+Rx
```

Any idea how to import a module with special characters like this?

Comment: *how* are you trying to import it?

Comment: Updated question (and found the answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html):

> Naming Your Product Module
>
> The name of the Xcode-generated header for Swift code, and the name of
>   the Objective-C bridging header that Xcode creates for you, are
>   generated from your product module name. By default, your product
>   module name is the same as your product name. However, if your product
>   name has any nonalphanumeric characters, such as a period (.), they
>   are replaced with an underscore (_) in your product module name. If
>   the name begins with a number, the first number is replaced with an
>   underscore.
>
> You can also provide a custom name for the product module name and
>   Xcode will use this when naming the bridging and generated headers. To
>   do this, change the Product Module Name build setting.
>
> NOTE
>
> You cannot override the product module name of a framework.

In your case, replace `NSObject+Rx` with `NSObject_Rx` or set your own name by changing the Product Module Name build setting.